# Network-manager: store secrets for automatic openvpn connection

Tags: openvpn, networkmanager, alpine-linux

Because I don't have access to a gui, I have added my openvpn password to the network-manager connection using:

```
$ sudo nmcli con mod CONNAME vpn.secrets "password=MYPASS"
```

I can confirm the password is stored by looking at the file with the connection name in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNAME.

I would expect to be able to activate this VPN connection by doing a

```
$ sudo nmcli c up CONNAME
```

however, it still fails after

```
Warning: password for 'vpn.secrets.cert-pass' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option. 
Error: Connection activation failed: No valid secrets
```

How do I store my password so that I don't need interaction to connect to my VPN?

Answer (score 1):

This is a different password needed.

In your /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNAME
try to add under:

```
[vpn]
...
cert-pass-flags=0
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't seem to make any difference. Can you tell me what the effect should have been and why?

Comment: It should not ask for a cert password if there's not one needed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "Secret flag types:" section in

```
man 5 nm-settings
```

Presently, it's right at the bottom (press G in the pager) and says

```
   Secret flag types:
       Each password or secret property in a setting has an associated flags property that describes how to handle that
       secret. The flags property is a bitfield that contains zero or more of the following values logically OR-ed together.

       •   0x0 (none) - the system is responsible for providing and storing this secret. This may be required so that secrets
           are already available before the user logs in. It also commonly means that the secret will be stored in plain text
           on disk, accessible to root only. For example via the keyfile settings plugin as described in the "PLUGINS"
           section in NetworkManager.conf(5).

       •   0x1 (agent-owned) - a user-session secret agent is responsible for providing and storing this secret; when it is
           required, agents will be asked to provide it.

       •   0x2 (not-saved) - this secret should not be saved but should be requested from the user each time it is required.
           This flag should be used for One-Time-Pad secrets, PIN codes from hardware tokens, or if the user simply does not
           want to save the secret.

       •   0x4 (not-required) - in some situations it cannot be automatically determined that a secret is required or not.
           This flag hints that the secret is not required and should not be requested from the user.
```

So to set that for my vpn I did

```
vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/myVpnName
```

Then under the `vpn` section:

```
[vpn]
...
password-flags=0
```

And the command you listed in your question should have created the `vpn-secrets` section:

```
[vpn-secrets]
password=myvpnpassword
```

Rember to reload the configuration and test using

```
# save the file
nmcli connection reload
nmcli connection up myVpnName
```

To confirm, I tested this with `password-flags=1` and got the same error as described in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me set:

password-flags=1 to password-flags=0
and
add
[vpn-secrets]
password=mypassword

My openvpn password was stored somewhere else maybe pam file and the order of execution caused that file not to be unlocked in time for the desktop to load.

Otherwise it would always popup the needs openvpn password on logging into Gnome session. Toggling LAN would then automatically connect, but I didn't want to keep hitting that button.